# First time crontab user, trying to learn by putting date/time periodically to stdout

Tags: osx, cron, date

I'm trying to learn how to use crontab to regularly execute bash commands.  I thought I'd try something simple first, like having crontab read the date and time to stdout every minute.  But when I try to do it, this is what happens:

```
Nicholass-MacBook-Air-2:cron_test nick$ crontab 1 * * * * date
crontab: 1: No such file or directory
```

How do I get this to work?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

enter the below line in your terminal

```
crontab -e
```

put the below line and save the file.

```
1 * * * * date >> /tmp/output.txt
```

after a minute, view the output file

```
cat /tmp/output.txt
```

Comment: It's been five minutes now, and /tmp/output.txt hasn't been created yet.

Comment: applogies, you have to use like

* * * * * date >> /tmp/output.txt

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Nicholass-MacBook-Air-2:~ nick$ crontab -l
1 * * * * date >> /tmp/output.txt

Comment: Nicholass-MacBook-Air-2:~ nick$ crontab -l

1 * * * * date >> /tmp/output.txt

Comment: * * * * * date >> /tmp/output.txt       

This doesn't specify the time interval

Comment: yes.. so it will run every minute. If you want to run only on 1st minute of every hour, then you have to use 1 *  * * *

Comment: @Kamaraj It won't on macOS, which doesn't use crontabs by default. The OP has a Mac of some sort.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that I'm running OS X El Capitan 10.11.5.  How do I make this execute in the terminal on a Mac?

Comment: I got launchctl to do what I was looking to do in crontab.  Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

The `crontab` command does not take the cron job entry on the command line.  To add a cron job entry, run `crontab -e` to open an editor.

On macOS, this will not work though, so you should prepare a text file with the cron entry in it and feed *that* into `crontab`:

```
$ vi crontab.txt   # use whatever editor you want
```

In there, add the entry:

```
* * * * * date >>/tmp/date.out
```

This entry is will schedule the `date` command to run every minute, forever (or until the cron job is deleted), and it will write its output to `/tmp/date.out`, adding a new line of output every time it runs.

Save the file and quit the editor.

Then, to actually load the cron entry:

```
$ crontab crontab.txt
```

Note, though, that this *replaces all existing crontab entries for the current user*, if there are any.

To *add* an entry on macOS, while preserving any already existing entries, first create `crontab.txt` with the existing crontab entries and edit that file and load it back in:

```
$ crontab -l >crontab.txt
$ vi crontab.txt
$ crontab crontab.txt
```

To remove *all* entries, use `crontab -r`.

Cron on macOS also understand the `@reboot`, `@hourly`, `@daily`, `@weekly` etc. short names for specific scheduling times. See [the `crontab(5)` manual](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/crontab.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/crontab) on your system for more info (`man 5 crontab`).